# Inject singleton on spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I got a Singleton class :

```
@Singleton
public class CacheManager {
    ...
}
```

In my Controller I want to inject this Singleton :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myRequest.do")
public class ListeSinistresController extends AFoaGanController {

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    ...
}
```

On deployment I got the following error :

```
<2 juin 2015 14 h 31 CEST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'listeSinistresController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.blabla.cache.CacheManager 
com.blabla.web.controller.personne.ListeSinistresController.cacheManager; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.blabla.cache.CacheManager] found for dependency:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

I tried to inject my singleton with `@Inject` - `@Authowired` - `@EJB`and nothing is working.

What's the way for doing this ?

Comment: Is the `com.blabla.cache` package configured to be scanned by Spring?

Comment: In which file is that configured ?

Comment: Ok, I found this in an xml file :  
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.blabla.aspects" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.blabla.web" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.blabla.delegate" />  
   
Is that you tell me about ?

Answer (score 0):

What's the package import of the Singleton? Could you try `@Component` annotation instead? (hint: all spring beans are singletons by default, if not explicit configured as `prototype`).

Also show your application config if the above does not work. Then package scanning is probably incorrect.

You have to use `@Autowired` with spring, that's correct.

Comment: The Singleton is in the com.blabla.cache package. The controller is in the package com.blabla.web.controller.personne package. @Component doesn't work.

Comment: I added this on configuration file and it didn't worked : 
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.blabla.cache" />